# Vector fields whose divergence are proper maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, polynomials, differential-equations, limit-cycles

Let $X$ be a polynomial  vector field  of degree $2$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Does there exist a nonvanishing  smooth function $g$ such that $Div(gX)$ is  a  proper map?Or at least the  zero locus of $Div(gX)=0$ is  a  compact set? Can we find this  $g$ an algebraic map or  at least in the  form $e^{P(x,y)}$ where $P$ is  a  polynomial?

Is there  a  uniform upper  bound $PDH(n)$ for the  number of  limit cycles of  a  those polynomial  vector  field of degree $n$ for which the  divergence is  proper or at least $Div=0$ is  a  compact  curve. For $n=3$, two what extent thses vector field  are classified in term of their coefficients

Comment: @PietroMajer  Thanks for the comments. Could you please more explain. for example the div of $(x^{2}+cy^{2})\partial_{x}+y^{2}\partial_{y}$ is not proper.

Comment: yes, now I see the point

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb R^2$ has one end and $\mathbb R^1$ has two ends, a proper map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^1$ must send the end of $\mathbb R^2$ to one of the two ends of $\mathbb R^1$ - that is, $f(x,y)$ is either a large positive number of a large negative number when $(x,y)$ is large.

But we can force $\nabla \cdot gX$ to oscillate  arbitrarily many times. Choose a vector field like $ \sin(x^2+y^2)( xdx + ydy)$. Then the integral of the divergence over a disc is the integral of the vector field dot the normal vector over a circle, which switches sign periodically in the radius of the function, so the divergence must switch sign arbitrarily often, so it can't be proper.

Moreover because it switches sign with arbitrarily large radius, the set where it is 0 cannot be compact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can not see why this is the answer to the first part of my question.Could you please more explain.